# can .vbs file be a scheduled script?

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks, windows-shell, wsh

I have written a .vbs script which presently is run manually by users. How can I make this script schedule itself in Task Scheduler (to run at a fixed time each day automatically) on Windows XP and Windows 7 the first time it is executed manually?

**EDIT**

```
    Option Explicit

    Dim oShell : Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.Shell")
    Dim FSO : set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
    Dim StartTime,Elapsed 

    'msgBox(oShell.CurrentDirectory)
    'MsgBox(FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder )
    oShell.CurrentDirectory = FSO.GetFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName).ParentFolder

    StartTime = Timer

    oShell.run "ParentChildLinkFinal.vbs", 1, True
    oShell.run "Parent_Child_Merge_final.vbs", 1, True
    oShell.run "CycleTime.vbs", 1, True
    oShell.run "Baddata.vbs", 1, True
    oShell.run "Matrixrefresh.vbs", 1, True

    Elapsed = Timer - StartTime

    MsgBox("Total time taken to finish this task:" & Elapsed & "in Seconds")
```

Thanks,

Comment: See http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/09/18/create-a-powershell-scheduled-job.aspx

Comment: @Tomalak Can all the commands we put in a script like file, as my end users are not much educated such to do.So if all the things could be made in a script,that would be better.

Comment: Can anyone take a look into this?

Answer (score 2):

Create a scheduled task to run the following command:

```
c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe PATH_TO_YOUR_VBS
```

Comment: but how this command can be scheduled? its again need to run by manual click right?

Comment: Use the [Windows Task Scheduler](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+task+scheduler)

Comment: i just gone [task scheduler page](http://www.iopus.com/guides/winscheduler.htm) and a bit confused that,to schedule the task shall I need to put my .vbs in `C:\\` drive or I can put the same to any of the full directory. And one more thing Can I do such manual settings via script,so that once any user first time `RUN` the .vbs script, .vbs will be scheduled then forever. - this way i think we can help the non-technical people much more.So is there any?

Comment: You can put the VBS file anywhere accessible to the user that the scheduled task executes as. You must pass the full path to the VBS file to cscript.exe. If you want to make your script self-installing as a scheduled task, that's going to be quite a bit more involved. If you expand your original question to describe *what* your script does and *why*, you may get other solutions which take a different approach that's more appropriate.

Comment: That doesn't help at all. You haven't explained (in text, not code) *what* tasks need to be accomplished - just that a set of scripts have to be run.

Comment: Yes, you are right! and that main.vbs i want to be set as scheduled taks! but not manually. Fits time the users would click on that file to start and that time it should be added to schedule task list forever!

Comment: See, now you're asking a *completely* different question. What you really want to know is "how can I create a WSH script which will install itself as a scheduled task when it's run for the first time." That's much more involved, and will vary depending on which version(s) of Windows you're running.

Comment: windows xp n 7 we are using

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly make a vbs file a scheduled task.

The caveat, though, is you want NOTHING to prompt the user...no inputs, no message boxes, nothing. Make sure you've handled and logged your exceptions or you could find yourself with a task that never completes (or worse, operations angrily calling you because a message box popped up at 3am and halted a production process)

Comment: I want the users to be prompted up a message by saying that - will they like this .vbs file(task) as scheduled or want to run manually every time? according to their response the scripts behavior will be determined.

Comment: Depends on what you're doing. Most of my VBS work has been on servers and running at times when nobody's around. If you've got someone there, I guess you could use a prompt...just know that code won't complete until someone interacts with the prompt (which may or may not be what you want depending on your requirement).

Comment: can i have such code which you would use or you can `edit` my code too please?

Answer (score 0):

on Windows 8: windows tasks that are triggering VBScripts having message boxes will only display the message boxes if the windows task is run under the same user who really is logged on the machine and the if the windows task is configured to "run only if the user is logged on"
I think this changed on windows 8, as on windows 7 I did not had to configure the task in that way

Answer (score -3):

try this

```
X=MsgBox("Take the Quiz!")

name=inputbox("Name")

q1=inputbox("Question 1 - How many days are there in a leap Year?")

q2=inputbox("Question 2 - How many Suns does Neptune have?")

q3=inputbox("Question 3 - What is your name?")

q4=inputbox("Question 4 - What did one computer say to the other?")

q5=inputbox("Question 5 - Why did the chicken cross the road?")

msgbox("Answers!")

msgbox("Q1 - How many days are there in a leap Year?, you answered ") + q1 + (" ,the correct answer is 366")

msgbox("Q2 - How many Suns does Neptune have?, you answered ") + q2 + (" ,the correct answere is one, our sun.")

msgbox("Q3 - What is your name?, you answered ") + q3 + (", the correct answer is ") + name + (" or is it?")

msgbox("Q4 - What did one computer say to the other?, you answered ") + q4 + (", the correct answer is, 011100110111010101110000 (Binary code for sup)")

msgbox("Q5 - Why did the chicken cross the road?, you answered ") + q5 + (", the correct answer is To get to the other side")

msgbox("Well done, ") + name + (" you have completed the quiz")
```