# Windows Task Scheduler Doesn't Run VBScript to Send an Email Through Outlook even when user is logged on

Tags: vbscript, scheduled-tasks

I know there have been a few topics on this and have tried all of the suggestions.

I am trying to run a vbs script to send an email with an attachment through task scheduler. It runs perfectly from command prompt, batch file, or Windows, but hangs when run through the task scheduler.

Email-9Y.vbs:

```
On Error Resume Next

AutoEmail

Sub AutoEmail()

    'config variable
    email = "email@dsaw.com"
    name = "Test"
    subject = "9Y Recon"
    docName = "9Y.xlsx"
    docAddress = "F:\Apps\Scripts\Recon 9Y\"
    
    
    ' create outlook app and account object
    Set xOutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    ' create mail item
    Set xOutMail = xOutApp.CreateItem(0)
    'construct the mail item
    With xOutMail
        .to = email
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .subject = subject
        .BodyFormat = 2
    '.Textbody = "Test"
        '.HTMLBody = GetHTMLBody(name, "document", phone, docName, inq)
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "email@dsaw.com"
        .Attachments.Add docAddress & docName
        '.display
        .Send
        End With
End Sub
```

email.bat:

```
wscript.exe "%~dp0Email-9Y.vbs" >> "%~dp0log.txt"
exit
```

Windows 10.
I have 'run only when user is logged on' and 'run with highest privilages' checked. I have tried using cscript and wscript. I have created the folders 'C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop' and 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile\Desktop'. I've tried running cmd with '/c start cscript //nologo "W:\Pathto with spaces\VBScript.vbs"'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running .vbs through task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31193573)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [can .vbs file be a scheduled script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14086918)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.vbs script runs in batch file but not when run through task scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58120111)

Comment: None of those help.